# Convolutional Neural Network Loss

Tags: tensorflow

While Calculating the Loss Function. Can i manually Calculate Loss like

Loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(np.array(Prediction) - np.array(Y)))

and then Optimize this Loss using Adam Optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 
Tensorflow loss functions typically accept tensors as input and also outputs a tensor. So np.array() wouldn't work.

In case of CNNs, you'd generally come across loss functions like cross-entropy, softmax corss-entropy, sigmoid cross-entropy etc. These are already in-built in tf.losses module. So you can use them directly. 
The loss function that you're trying to apply looks like a Mean-squared loss. This is built in tf.losses as well. tf.losses.mean_squared_error.

Having said that, I've also implemented a few loss functions like cross-entropy using hand-coded formula such as: **-tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(targets * logProb))**. This works equally fine, as long as the inputs **targets** and **logProb** are computed as tensors and not as numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

No, actually you need to use **tensor Variable** for **Loss**, not use `numpy.array`(`np.array(Prediction)`).

Since **tensorflow** will `eval` these `tensors` in **tensorflow** engine.